# CSS Grid to make a floating sidebar on desktop that stacks for mobile

Tags: html, css, css-grid

I am trying to use css grid to create a right sidebar that on mobile will convert to the top and be stacked up top. However, my code for some reason it works great on the page load but it does not shrink the 1fr section when the screen collapses. I would have thought 1fr would shrink to the available space since i set the side bar at a fixed 350px. Any ideas? Also how would I set this up css wise for a stacked grid where the fixed sidebar goes on top then at full width.

```
.grid-container{
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: auto 350px;
  grid-template-rows: 1fr;
  grid-template-areas: "table-section filter-section";
}
.table-section{
  grid-area: table-section;
}
.filter-section{
  grid-area: filter-section;
}
```

My html is as follows:

```
  <div class="full-height" :class="$q.screen.lt.md ? 'grid-container-mobile' : 'grid-container'">
    <div class="col table-section q-pa-md">
    </div>
    <div class="col-auto filter-section q-pa-md">
      <TableFilters />
    </div>
  </div>
```

For some reason it does not collapse so the shrinking window size results in a overflow:
[image]

[image]

As you can see the 1fr section is not shrinking as if the width on initial load is fixed.

Comment: Please [create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: As Tim R already mentioned. Create a minimal reproducible example i.e. please create a simplified markup for the entire layout (html + css, all the necessary) using some divs with a background-color and some sample text and post it here with the undesired effect. Otherwise, it is super hard to tell. We cannot debug images. The posted code looks +/- okay. Could be that some of your components have a minimum width or something set that prevents the container from shrinking.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `@media` query, [link here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_media_queries/Using_media_queries), this allows you to use different rules depending on what condition you put inside the media query.

For example you could use

```css
@media screen and (orientation: portrait) {

}
```

This isn't the best method to detect a mobile client but will always work when it is a mobile client but will also work on any portrait display.

With that, here is how I would structure your elements and the CSS to go with it.

```html
<div class='container'>
   <div class='calendar'>

   </div>
   <div class='filter'>

   </div>
</div>
```

```css
.container {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.calendar {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
}

.filter {
    width: 350px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

@media screen and (orientation: landscape) {
    /* media condition could be changed, just for example */
    
    .container {
        flex-flow: column-reverse;
        height: 100%;
    }

    .calendar {
        height: 100%;
        max-height: 100%;
    }

    .filter {
        height: 250px; /* whatever height you want it to be */
    }

}
```

Comment: Thanks and I am familiar with @media queries but I am more curious how css grid would work for a right sidebar menu. When i refresh the screen everthing appears perfect. However, collapsing the screen does not reduce 1fr.

Comment: @IrishRedneck I can't put your HTML into a codepen as it displays nothing, but from your paragraph, which I may be wrong about as I couldn't understand it very well, the thing you are looking for may be `grid-template-areas` in CSS [link here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/grid-template-areas), this allows you to define which columns and rows the different children will go into

Comment: So i have updated my code to use that but still. How do you do css grid with a fixed column to the right and the left is collapsing?

Comment: it is almost as if the width is fixed.

Comment: @IrishRedneck for that you need to use `grid-template-columns: 1fr 200px;`

Comment: @IrishRedneck ok I understand now, this should fix it `grid-template-columns: 0 1fr;`

Comment: Check out my edit with pics to be more clear. I cannot get the desktop version to work currently. I want the sidebar to remain fixed but the table section to shrink in width with the screen so no overflow. The mobile we can tackle after.

Comment: I'm just going to ask everything I need to know because I still can't really understand what you want. Is the part you're trying to edit the calendar section and the filter section to the right of it? Why have you added a `grid-template-rows: 1fr;` to your CSS, this won't do anything since you only have 1 row. What do you mean when you say you want the left to collapse? And finally, what are the 2 screenshots depicting? The first screenshot is the desktop version? and the second is the mobile version? I don't know what the context difference is between the two screenshots.

Comment: The pic shows the desktop version. It shows there is an overflow rather than the width collapsing. Almost like the width of the grid is fixed. I want the table section to shrink in width and the sidebar to remain fixed in width

Comment: Your approach works. For the mobile what would you r@ media query look like to get the filter above above calendar? I had tried flex like you but when I would do order 2 on the nth child it would actually reverse all the stuff inside the child divs. So curious how you would do this. That solves all my issues. THe overflow turns out was something inside my tabs causing the issue.

Comment: @IrishRedneck new edit should now get what you want with the mobile version too. You would add `flex-flow: column-reverse;` to make it so it makes the flexbox go into rows instead of columns, and then it also reverses the order of the elements. Also could you mark this answer as the correct one so the question will be answered for other people to see, if it does work ofcourse.